# Is compatible Jasny fileupload plugin + blueimp fileupload?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, blueimp, jasny-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Jasny fileupload plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) for the design and [Blueimp fileupload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload images at the same time. I don't know if I'm doing it right.

The whole website is designed in Bootstrap and the Jasny fileupload plugin was imposed. I chose to use the Blueimp fileupload plugin because it's flexible, I can validate the type and the volume of the uploaded file and so on...

So while I select an image, the Blueimp fileupload uploads the photo on the server without any problem, but the Jasny fileupload doesn't move. The preview area stays empty. The thumnnail doesn't appear in the area. Also the "Select" button doesn't change to "Change" and "Remove" buttons.

If i comment the lines:

```
<script src="https://.../js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="https://.../js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

the Jasny fileupload works, the thumbnail is shown and the Select button becomes Change and Remove buttons, but the images can't be uploaded of course :)

Is it a compatibility problem or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you been able to get jasny and blueimp working together because I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Note that this is no longer an issue with Bootstrap 3, since the plugin has been renamed to 'file input'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a namespace clash between Blueimp fileupload and Jasny fileupload. [See this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues/17)

You can work around this by changing th (blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) widget factory namespace from

```
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {....
```

to

```
e.g $.widget('blueimp.fileuploader', {....
```

Comment: This worked for me! The toughest part was to understand that the events on('fileuploaddone')... etc need to be renamed as well to on('fileuploaderdone').